# argparse: ArgumentParser().add_subparsers: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'required'

Tags: pypy

I'm trying to figure out why this test case doesn't work on latest PyPy, but works on Python 3:

```
__import__("argparse").ArgumentParser().add_subparsers(required=True, dest="action")
```

Is there a backported version of argparse I could pull in to bypass this error?

Comment: Please clarify "works on Python 3", because I tried on CPython 3.6.9 and it returns the same error as pypy3.6 v7.3.1.

Comment: @RonanLamy: that's true. It could be that I was testing under Python 3.7 and PyPy seems to target Python 3.6.9.

Comment: You can try the 3.7 pre-release nightly builds at http://buildbot.pypy.org/nightly/py3.7/